# Small Printer Robot that moves over printed surface

Tags: printer, printing

I remember seeing (could be 10 or 20 years ago, on something like BBC's old Tomorrows World program) small - robotic - printers with wheels that moved over the surface to be printed. They were ideal for printing on paper or canvas that physically could not run through a printer.

Apologies if SuperUser isn't the place to ask this

I have a requirement for something that can do this, I tried googling but with no success.

Do these things still exist? If so what are they called? Where can I pick one up?

**Clarification**
This wouldn't be printing on paper, it would be printing on a flat surface of a manufactured product, the surface cannot be covered by paper or plastic.
also, they were actual manufactured products, [not this home made version](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B17ILk1O4Xs)

Comment: Sorry but Super User is not a place to ask this. Check out Ars Technica or Tom's Hardware forums

Comment: @Sathya: That's what I was afraid of, thanks for the tips :)

Answer (score 0):

Most of the stuff I can find on the internet is DIY build your own stuff, i searched for robot plotter and got some results that way